# New items using chrome.pushMessaging API cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web Store anymore

Tags: google-chrome-app

Has anyone encountered the below problem when trying to upload a chrome app for doing push messaging to the developer dashboard? How do you fix it?

+++

Developer Dashboard > Add new item
Upload an extension or app (.zip file)
zzzz.zip (Server rejected)
Retry
Choose file Upload
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

New items using chrome.pushMessaging API cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web Store anymore.

+++

Here's the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "zzzzz",
  "description": "zzzzz",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "app" : {
    "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["app.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions" : [
     "notifications",
     "storage",
     "audioCapture",
     "pushMessaging",
     "gcm", 
     "http://*/",
     "https://*/"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to the [newer API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm).
**Here's the announcement blog post:** [Moving Towards a Single Cloud Messaging API](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/moving-towards-single-cloud-messaging.html)

You need to get rid of `"pushMessaging"` permission, and any calls to `chrome.pushMessaging` API.

Considering that your manifest mentions `"gcm"` permission, it's possible you actually implemented the newer GCM API, but accidentally put in the old permission.

Comment: That is correct. You can also get more information on  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcm-for-chrome-feedback group.